# Determing which Item was Clicked in a Custom Menu

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-apps-script-editor

I've created a custom menu with multiple items in it, however I'm having difficulties determining which item was clicked by the user. I want to use the same function for every item in this menu but I can't figure out how to pass on the info of which item was pressed into my function. Multiple ideas that I've had but haven't been able to implement are: trying to pass a parameter when pressing a button (the parameter could be the name of the button or its index), or trying to somehow determine which item was clicked by index (i.e. "item 3 was clicked") and passing that info on to the function.

```
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); //shortcut to access ui methods
var ps = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties(); //shortcut to access properties methods
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() //shortcut to access spreadsheet methods

function onOpen() {
  var menu = ui.createMenu('Scripts') //create a menu with this name
  var subMenu = ui.createMenu('Timestamps')
        for (var n = 0; n < ss.getNumSheets(); n++){
          var sheets = ss.getSheets();
          var sheetName = sheets[n].getName();
          Logger.log(sheetName)
          subMenu.addItem(sheetName, 'sheets')
        }
      menu.addSubMenu(subMenu).addToUi(); //add it to the UI
}

function sheets(sheet){
  var response = ui.alert(sheet, 'Add to timestamps?', ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO_CANCEL) //create a button and store the user value in response
  if(response == ui.Button.YES){ //if the user pressed YES (add this item to timestamp list)
    if(sheets.indexOf(sheet) != -1){ //check if item is already in the array. If it is, do nothing
      //item is aleady in array
    }else if(sheets.indexOf(sheet) == -1){ //check if it is NOT in the array. If it isn't, add it
      //item isn't in array, but needs to be added
      sheets.push(sheet) //add the item to the array
    }
  }else if(response == ui.Button.NO){ //if the user pressed NO (remove item from the list)
    if(sheets.indexOf(sheet) != -1){ //if the item already exists but needs to be removed)
      //item exists in array, but needs to be removed
      var index = sheets.indexOf(sheet); //find where the item is stored
      sheets.splice(index, 1); //splice that item out of the array
    }else if(sheets.indexOf(sheet) == -1){ //if the item already doesn't exist in the array, do nothing
      //item already isn't in array
    }
  }
  ps.setProperty('updatedSheets', JSON.stringify(sheets)) //storing the new value of sheets so that we can view it in the properties screen (only for debugging purposes)
}
```

What this code currently does is when the spreadsheet is opened, a menu is created named `Scripts` with a sub-menu inside of it named `Timestamps`. Inside of the sub-menu timestamps, I have one item for each sheet. The purpose is that when the user clicks on one of the items, a pop-up appears with 3 buttons: Yes, No, and Cancel. If they press Yes, that item is supposed to be added to the array sheets. If they press No, that item is supposed to be removed. If they press Cancel, nothing happens. I have it working so far to add and remove the items if they specify in the code a specific sheet, but how could I get it so that I could use the same function for every item and pass the parameter sheet (depending on which item was clicked) into the function sheets.

Example of the functionality of the code if I hard-code the sheet name without passing a parameter to the function:

```
function sheets(){
  var response = ui.alert('Sheet1', 'Add to timestamps?', ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO_CANCEL) //create a button and store the user value in response
  if(response == ui.Button.YES){ //if the user pressed YES (add this item to timestamp list)
    if(sheets.indexOf('Sheet1') != -1){ //check if item is already in the array. If it is, do nothing
      //item is aleady in array
    }else if(sheets.indexOf('Sheet1') == -1){ //check if it is NOT in the array. If it isn't, add it
      //item isn't in array, but needs to be added
      sheets.push('Sheet1') //add the item to the array
    }
  }else if(response == ui.Button.NO){ //if the user pressed NO (remove item from the list)
    if(sheets.indexOf('Sheet1') != -1){ //if the item already exists but needs to be removed)
      //item exists in array, but needs to be removed
      var index = sheets.indexOf('Sheet1'); //find where the item is stored
      sheets.splice(index, 1); //splice that item out of the array
    }else if(sheets.indexOf('Sheet1') == -1){ //if the item already doesn't exist in the array, do nothing
      //item already isn't in array
    }
  }
  ps.setProperty('updatedSheets', JSON.stringify(sheets)) //storing the new value of sheets so that we can view it in the properties screen (only for debugging purposes)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know `eval` is evil but I cannot help using it. Yes, if you make a bunch of functions dynamically via `eval` then the rest is trivial.

```
var FUNC_STR = 'sheets';  //the real function name (global constant)

function onOpen() {
  //...
  for(var n = 0; n < ss.getNumSheets(); n++){
    var sheets = ss.getSheets();
    var sheetName = sheets[n].getName();
    subMenu.addItem(sheetName, FUNC_STR + n);  //note here
  }
  menu.addSubMenu(subMenu).addToUi();
}


//dynamically make functions
var evalString = '';
for(var n = 0; n < ss.getNumSheets(); n++) {
  evalString += 'function ' + FUNC_STR + n + '() { ' + 
    FUNC_STR + '(' + n + ') }';
}
eval(evalString);


//now you can take a argument.
//function name should be the same as FUNC_STR.
function sheets(sheet) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(sheet);
  //...
}
```

Comment: The solution implies that you call the same function but from different sheets, and you can pass the `which sheet` info with your trick, correct?  In that case I assume it's better than nothing :)